# Trying to do preg_match as well as match entire string length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, strlen

Is there a way to incorporate preg_match with total string length? I need to be able to match alphanumeric, with single underscores inside the string, with a total string length <= n.

Currently what I'm working with is this:

`preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/',$string) && (strlen($string) <= 10)`

I have played around with this for too long, trying to incorporate the entire thing into preg_match, so just tacked on the `&& strlen`, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
preg_match('/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*).{1,10}$/', $string)
```

**edit** according to comments:

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$).{5,25}$/
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$).{5,25}$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Za-z0-9]+             any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to
                             'z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Za-z0-9]+             any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to
                               'z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{5,25}                  any character except \n (between 5 and 25
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**[Infos on look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

Comment: Thanks - this was very helpful, but I did need to modify it slightly to fit my needs. Specifically, string could not start or stop with any character (must be alpha-numeric), so I ended up with this:

`preg_match('/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*).{5,25}(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])$/',$string)`

Comment: No, that's not working. I think it's a problem with `*).` but I can't quite figure it out at the moment. My goal is to match `this_string` or `this_one_too`, but `_not_th!s_string` or `this_one_`.

As it is now, this regex will match `d___@____!____#___d`, and that's not good.

Comment: Yes, that works. I see `*` was replaced with `+`, and added a `$`. I think I know what's going on now, and overused lookbehind :) I love regex, because it's such a challenge!